# Search and Replace in a String with values stored in an array without a loop

Tags: php, string

How can I do a search and replace in a string when my search values are stored in an array of strings?

```
$strFromSearchBox = 'Why you foo, bar, I ought to tar you';

$theseWords       = array('foo', 'bar', 'tar');
```

So, I'd like to replace `foo` `bar` `tar` in the string with blanks. Is it possible without using a `while` or `for` loop?

Comment: str_replace (). It's in the manual!

Comment: Yes it is. The PHP manual tells you how: http://php.net/str_replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) accepts arrays as arguments.

```
$output = str_replace($theseWords, ' ', $strFromSearchBox);
```

Comment: This was good. Never knew it could be done this way.

Answer (score 1):

[`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) accepts arrays!

```
str_replace(array(
    'foo',
    'bar',
    'tar'
), '', 'Why you foo, bar, I ought to tar you');
```

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for `str_replace`

```
$string = 'Why you foo, bar, I ought to tar you';
$result = str_replace(
   array( 'foo', 'bar', 'tar'), 
   '', 
   $string
);
```